# Avoid duplicate link to same page with #

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, links, sitelinks, link-building

I have one link in main nav `example.com/photo` but i want to add more links on page, which go on same page as this nav.

Will this `example.com/photo#` help me avoid duplicate link to same page?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "duplicate links"? These are simply in-page links, there's no "duplicate content" here.

Comment: Well i got this request from my employer to include in my links, his "SEO guy" told him this, so i am just checking if this is true or not?

Comment: Does this have any sense, to put # on end, and nothing is after it?

Comment: Links on the same page, to the current page(?), but with `#` appended? I'm not sure that I follow exactly? Simply adding `#` (an empty fragment identifier) on the URL does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Adding these links on homepage, to go on a new page /photo, but as i said i have /photo included also in main nav. My tought exactly is that this doesn't make sence, that is why i am asking question here :)

Comment: Are you referring to page anchors which jump to different parts of the same page?

Comment: No not anchors, just regular links. For example, on homepage, if i have multiple links (this case 2) on page that goes to the page /photo, will it help in some way to add # on end to avoid duplicate links. As @w3d said these are just in-page links, there is no duplicate content problem here. Right? and having duplicated links on page is not a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate links is not an SEO issue unless someone is doing page rank sculpting, in which case use `rel=nofollow` on the duplicate link (though I really wouldn't bother as I don't think this works any more, and it was of negligible benefit when it did.)

If you mean is a `#` on the end of a URL counted as a separate page, then no it is not.  It is an anchor to the same page.

Even if it did count as a separate link, Google would just choose one of them as canonical.

Answer (score 3):

You can have two or more links from one page A to a page B. There is no issue here. You are not going to be penalized. There is no need to avoid duplicate links to same page. Your SEO guy is wrong.